# HTML and Javscript field returning NaN, when field is blank

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a webapp, and the formatting of the one text field is working almost perfectly, however, the only thing that is happening I do not want to happen is when I click out of the field and there is no value, it returns `NaN`

**HTML**

```
  <input type="text" class="rounded" name="sname" id="investamt" onblur="handleChange()"><br>
```

**Javascript**

```
var fnf = document.getElementById("investamt");
fnf.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt){
    var n = parseInt(this.value.replace(/\D/g,''),10);
    fnf.value = n.toLocaleString();
}, false);

function handleChange() {
   var myValue = document.getElementById("investamt").value;

   if (myValue.indexOf("$") != 0)
   {
      myValue = "$" + myValue;
   }

   document.getElementById("investamt").value = myValue;
}
```

Why is it returning NaN when I click out of the text field and it is blank, I would like it to return 0 instead, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the value and zero it out with `if (isNaN(n)) n = 0;`

```js
var fnf = document.getElementById("investamt");
fnf.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
  var n = parseInt(this.value.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
  if (isNaN(n)) n = 0;
  fnf.value = n.toLocaleString();
}, false);

function handleChange() {
  var myValue = document.getElementById("investamt").value;

  if (myValue.indexOf("$") != 0) {
    myValue = "$" + myValue;
  }

  document.getElementById("investamt").value = myValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="rounded" name="sname" id="investamt" onblur="handleChange()"><br>
```

Comment: Oh, see I was trying to work on like an if else statement there, I was over thinking, this worked perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

when you parse something empty string it will return NAN. try this on console:--

```
parseInt(''.replace(/\D/g,''),10)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code....
hope it will fill your requirments :)

```js
var fnf = document.getElementById("investamt");
        fnf.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt){
            var n 
            n = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')
            fnf.value = n;
        }, false);

        function handleChange() {
        var myValue = document.getElementById("investamt").value;
            if(myValue.length === 0){ myValue = '0'}
        if (myValue.indexOf("$") != 0)
        {
            myValue = "$" + myValue;
        }

        document.getElementById("investamt").value = myValue;
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" class="rounded" name="sname" id="investamt" onblur="handleChange()"><br>
```